# What is significance of putting "$" sign before a parameter in Java / Android?

Tags: java, android

What is the difference or significance of putting $ sign before any variable or parameter..

e.g.

Suppose here is my class...

```
 public class Vector3 {
      public Vector3(float x, float y, float z){
           //...
          //... my ctor code
          //...
      }
 }
```

and what will be the difference between these two declarations...

**Declaration 1**

```
 Vector3 $vec = new Vector3(1f,1f,1f);
```

**Declaration 2**

```
 Vector3 vec = new Vector3(1f,1f,1f);
```

If you can notice $ sign before "vec" in Declaration 1 and Declaration 2.

Any clues?

Also, declaring the same constructor as below,

```
public class Vector3 {

    public Vector3(float $x, float $y, float $z){
    //...
    //... my ctor code
    //...
    }
}
```

What is difference between above constructor and the initial constructor ?

Thanks...

Edit: Thanks to all your responses, I did this with different combinations and there is no major significance :) I appreciate all your answers.

Comment: Where did you see that? If it's allowed (which I don't know) it may just be an old habit of PHP programmers.

Comment: It is running successfully here at : http://code.google.com/p/min3d/source/browse/trunk/src/min3d/vos/Number3dManaged.java?r=80

Comment: In that code they are using C#'s conventions for interface naming and naming private fields. And PHP's convention on naming variables. It's pretty ugly mutant, I don't understand why someone needs to update very clear and brilliant java naming conventions.

Comment: after a lot of exercise, I found something really interesting about this framework, he is trying to segregate "Managed" and "UnManaged" vectors and 3d co-ordinates by "$" sign. 

I have already emailed him to get the concrete meaning of this million "$" sign.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#40625), it's permissible, but has no special meaning. Note that the specification goes on to recommend that it "only be used in mechanically generated source code, or rarely, to access pre-existing names in a legacy system".

Comment: +1 Yay, I couldn't find the link about the "recommended" bit.

Comment: The recommend part can be found at: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8

Answer (score 13):

compiles and runs. kid you not.

```
package $;

public class $
{
    int $;

    int $(int $){ return $; }
    void $$(int $){ this.$=$; }

    $ _(){ return this; }

    $ _;

    {
        $$($($));

        _._()._._()._();
    }
}
```

Comment: of course it is compilable, but it is so funny xD haha the dollar sign and underscore looks like operator so it may confuse people hehehe

Comment: It is an interesting piece of code, showing the extreme of java.

Answer (score 7):

While many people have pointed out that `$` is [legal in identifiers](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#367), I refute the use of `$` (at least as an initial token) as it goes against the [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#367):

> **Variable names should not start with underscore _ or dollar sign $ characters**, even though both are allowed.

While this does not include the case of `foo$bar` I follow the JLS recommendation that the `$` be used *only in generated code*. The Java compiler uses `$` when it generates anonymous classes, for instance.

If nothing else, I would consider your code ugly :-)

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe it is anything more than a valid symbol for use in Java variable names. From the Java tutorial on variables ( http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html ):

> **Variable names are case-sensitive. A variable's name can be any legal identifier — an unlimited-length sequence of Unicode letters and digits, beginning with a letter, the dollar sign "$", or the underscore character "_".** The convention, however, is to always begin your variable names with a letter, not "$" or "_". Additionally, the dollar sign character, by convention, is never used at all. You may find some situations where auto-generated names will contain the dollar sign, but your variable names should always avoid using it. A similar convention exists for the underscore character; while it's technically legal to begin your variable's name with "_", this practice is discouraged. White space is not permitted.

Answer (score 0):

> Variable names are case-sensitive. A variable's name can be any legal identifier — an unlimited-length sequence of Unicode letters and digits, beginning with a letter, the dollar sign "$", or the underscore character "*". The convention, however, is to always begin your variable names with a letter, not "$" or "*". Additionally, the dollar sign character, by convention, is never used at all. You may find some situations where auto-generated names will contain the dollar sign, but your variable names should always avoid using it. A similar convention exists for the underscore character; while it's technically legal to begin your variable's name with "_", this practice is discouraged. White space is not permitted.

Taken from : ttp://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html#naming