# How to form a regex to recognize correct declaration of variable names

Tags: java, regex

I would like to form a regex ro recognize the declaration of a variable name. User will enter a string that they would like as a variable name, and the program has to check whether the variable is valid.

1. The first character of the variable name must either be alphabet or underscore. It should not start with the digit.
2. No commas and blanks are allowed in the variable name.
3. No special symbols other than underscore are allowed in the variable name.

I have been trying for the whole day and couldn't get the correct one.

Comment: just for the record: java allows using `$` in any place in variable names

Answer (score 56, accepted):

First thing we do is gather a list of all the valid characters for the first character:

```
[a-zA-Z_$]
```

Then the other characters:

```
[a-zA-Z_$0-9]
```

we want to match the whole string, and we can have 0 or more of the other characters, so the regex becomes:

```
^[a-zA-Z_$][a-zA-Z_$0-9]*$
```

I allow capital characters in the first character in the regex (as well as dollar signs), because this is a test for **validity**, not for well-formed variables. (Note that constants *should* be in all caps, including the first letter.)

`\w` matches `a-zA-Z0-9_`, so the above regex can be shortened further to the following (with a slight loss in clarity):

```
^[a-zA-Z_$][\w$]*$
```

Comment: How would one apply the above knowledge to **replace** any **invalid** characters found in a potential variable name? I am looking for something more streamlined than `textOrg.replace("!", "").replace("(", "").replace(",", "").replace(")", "").replace(".", "").replace("'", "").replace("&", "");`. Thanks!

Comment: @Alexander for that, you don't want to match the whole string, just the range of characters, so the regex from above would be simpified to `[!().,&]` and replace all occurrences of that with `""`

Answer (score 7):

You can use this:

```
"^[_a-z]\\w*$"
```

How it works:

```
^        // Match at the beginning
[_a-z]   // Match either "_", or "a-z" at the beginning 
\\w*     // Match zero or more of characters - [a-zA-Z0-9_], after the beginning
$        // Till the end
```

Note - according to *Java Naming Convention*, a variable should *not* start with an *uppercase letter*, so I have not included - `[A-Z]` in the first character class.

Also, since Java allows the use of `$` in the variable name, even at the start, you should consider adding it to your allowed character set. So, you can modify the above regex as:

```
"^[_$a-z][\\w$]*$"
```

Comment: why double slash? \\ ? Is that java specific? (I'm from Perl and its just a `\w` there.)

Comment: @Paulchenkiller. Yeah you are right. It's Java specific. Java requires the slash itself to be escaped.

Answer (score 3):

This will do what you want:

```
"^[a-z_]\\w*$"
```

Explanation:

- `^`: start at the beginning of the string
- `[a-z_]`: match a single lowercase letter or underscore
- `\\w*`: match zero or more word characters (`\w` is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`)
- `$`: match until the end of the string.

*Edit*: Updated to reflect the "dollar sign allowed" and "name shouldn't start with uppercase" pointed out by the others. Thanks for the reminder.

*Edit 2*: After doing some research I've removed the matching for dollar signs again. While technically permissible, it's certainly bad style in this context and therefore discouraged, just like variables starting with an uppercase letter. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/4636667/1814922