# Detecting variables through a string

Tags: java, regex, variables

I am creating a simple IDE using `JTextPane` and detecting keywords and coloring them.

Currently, I am able to detect:

1. Comments
2. String Literals
3. Integers & Floats
4. Keywords

The way I detect these types are through regular expressions.

Now, I am trying to detect variables like [int **x** = 10;] and coloring them a different color.

Currently, I am able to get all data types like int, float char using the following regex:

```
Pattern words = Pattern.compile(\\bint\\b|\\bfloat\\b\\bchar\\b);
Matcher matcherWords = words.matcher(code);
while (matcherWords.find()) {
    System.out.print(code.substring(matcherWords.start(), matcherWords.end());
    // How to get next word that is a variable?
}
```

Below is a sample output of my program:

[image]

How am I able to detect variables like `a`, `b`, `c` after I can detect `int`, `float`, etc?

Comment: May be you can use the regular expression for that.. like setting all the rules for a valid variable name and get the data till operator or semicolon appears.

Comment: Could you not detect when they're initialized via datatype and store the following word?

Comment: I see, sorry but im very very new to regex and i have no clue how to do such complex regex.

Comment: @Trobbins YESYES thats what i am trying to achieve. but i do not know how to get the "following word"

Comment: May be this will help you .. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17564142/3979057)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

```
(?:(?<=int|float|String|double|char|long)(?:\s+[a-zA-Z_$][\w$]*\s*)|(?<=\G,)(?:\s*[a-zA-Z_$][\w$]*\s*))(?=,|;|=)
```

which means:

- `(?<=int|float|String|double|char|long)` - positive lookbehind
  searching for variable type,
- `(?:\s+[a-zA-Z_$][\w$]*\s*)` - non capturing group: at least one space, followed by valid
  characters for Java variables, followed by zero or more spaces
- `|` - or; alternative between maching name after var. type or after comma,
- `(?<=\G,)` - positive lookbehind for previous match and comma (because other parts match spaces from both sides)
- `(?:\s*[a-zA-Z_$][\w$]*\s*)` - non capturing group: at least one space, followed by valid
  characters for Java variables, followed by zero or more spaces
- `(?=,|;|=)` - positive lookahead for comma, equal sign or semi-colon

it use a `\G` boundary matching ([The end of the previous match](http://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html)), so the alternative, which search names between other names (words beetween spaces or/and commas exactly), will match only if it is after previous match. So it will not match every word beetween commas in Strings for example. Also I added `$` in `[a-zA-Z_$][\w$]*` as it is [allowed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html) in variable names however not recommended.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lW4wA0/1)

And for Java:

```
 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?:(?<=int|float|String|double|char|long)(?:\\s+[a-zA-Z_$][\\w$]*\\s*)|(?<=\\G,)(?:\\s*[a-zA-Z_$][\\w$]*\\s*))(?=,|;|=)");
```

**EDIT**

You can use `(int |float |...)` to match names of variables directly using `matcher.start()` and `matcher.end()` without spaces, however I would rather use `(?:\s*)` in every place where space can ocour and then check for redundant spaces during data process, because you never know how much spaces will user type (of course more than one is redundant, but it is still valid!).

Another approuch would be to match spaces but use groups, like:

```
(?:(?<=int|float|String|double|char|long)(?:\s+)([a-zA-Z_$][\w$]*)(?:\s*)|(?<=\G,)(?:\s*)([a-zA-Z_$][\w$]*)(?:\s*))(?=,|;|=)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/oL4vX0/1)

names are without spaces, but you need to extract them from groups 1 & 2 by `matcher.start(group no)` and `matcher.end(group no)`.

**EDIT2** answer to question from comment

It depends what you want to achieve. If you just want to get variables as Strings, it is enough to use mathod `trim()` but if you want to get start and end indices of variables in text, to for example highlight it in different colour, it will be better to use for example `matcher.start(1)` to extract start index of group 1. Consider this example:

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String      text = "int a = 100;\n" +
                "float b = 100.10;\n" +
                "double c - 12.454545645;\n" +
                "long longest dsfsf = 453543543543;\n" +
                "a = d;\n" +
                "char     b = 'a';\n" +
                "String str = \"dfssffdsdfsd\"\n" +
                "int d,f,g;\n" +
                "int a,f,frhg = 0;\n" +
                "String string = \"a,b,c,d,e,f\"";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?:(?<=int|float|String|double|char|long)(?:\\s+)([a-zA-Z_$][\\w$]*)(?:\\s*)|(?<=\\G,)(?:\\s*)([a-zA-Z_$][\\w$]*)(?:\\s*))(?=,|;|=)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
        while(matcher.find()){
            System.out.println("trim(): " + text.substring(matcher.start(),matcher.end()).trim()); // cut off spaces by trim() method;

            int group = (matcher.group(1)==null)? 2 : 1; // check which group captured string;
            System.out.println("group(" + group + "): \n\t"  // to extract string by group capturing;
                    + text.substring(matcher.start(group),matcher.end(group))
                    + ",\n\tsubstring(" + matcher.start(group) + "," + matcher.end(group)+")");

        }
    }
}
```

the output present two approches.

Comment: Dude.. you are awesome !!

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. it seems like its working but could u explain how to extract the variable names without the spaces? For example, when i use matcher.group(), int a = 10 --> i get the variable " a". but what i want is just a. Thank you so much

Comment: what do u mean by " extract them from groups 1 & 2 by matcher.start(group no) and matcher.end(group no)."

Comment: @user3188291 I updated my answer, ask freely If you have more questions

Comment: Thank you so much! it works perfectly. Cleared all my doubts.

Comment: @user3188291. I think matching spaces isn't a problem, cause changing their text color won't produce anything.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried a lookbehind/lookahead pattern?

This ridiculously long pattern:

```
"(?<=int |float |String |double )([a-zA-Z_]\\w*)(?=,|;|\\s)|([a-zA-Z_]\\w*)(?=,|;|\\s*=)"
```

Is able to parse out variables and comma separated variables.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String javaCode = "int a = 100;\n" + 
            "float b = 110;\n" + 
            "String c = \"Hello World\";" +
            "double d, e, f, g = 1.0, h;";

    Matcher matcher = Pattern
            .compile("(?<=int |float |String |double )([a-zA-Z_]\\w*)(?=,|;|\\s)|([a-zA-Z_]\\w*)(?=,|;|\\s*=)")
            .matcher(javaCode);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
}
```

Results:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
```

Also tested here @ [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pW6fM7/5)

Comment: this doesnt work on multiple variables declaration like int a,b,c;. But thank you very much for your answer though..

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes Updated answer will not pick up the function name.  Still looking into comma delimited variables.

Comment: Thank you for the update.. Any luck with comma delimited variables though?

Comment: @user3188291 Right now, someone who's better at regex than I am will have to speak for the comma delimited variables.  Otherwise I'd suggest detecting a variable declaration line and split out the variable names by the comma.  I'll look at this more later.  Excellent question posted!

Comment: Thanks for the update, but it is not working 100% consistently like boolean b = true will detect true as a variable name as well.. But your help is very much appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
\b(?:int|float|String|char|double|long)\b\s+([^=;]+)
```

Did you tried to match only the variable name? If yes then the above one will help.

Comment: Ahh,, this Almost works... currently, this regex matches "int a".. but what im trying to get is only a

Comment: check the latest version as I've edited few times. And check the right side the match section. https://regex101.com/r/xQ5fK9/1

Comment: Thank you for your answer, in the regex101 website, it matches the variable name. But when i tried matching it in my program using matcher.start(), matcher.end(), i get int a, float b... but what i wanted is only the variable name a & b... Is it a wrong way to use matcher.start() and matcher.end()?

Comment: Could you try the regexp this way? Maybe matcher would like it better. If not then will need to ask someone who knows Java, as I'm not that person.
`(?:\b(?:int|float|String|char|double|long)\b\s+)([^=;]+)`